# identifier expected error when creating user defined function

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION db.scalar_func
(
    @a AS INT, 
    @b AS INT 
)
RETURNS INT -- return type
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @a + @b -- return statement
END;
```

I was trying the above code to test user defined functions however it states expecting an identifier.
Anyone has any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: This looks like code for microsoft sql server, it is tagged as mysql though. You may want to look for a different tutorial/guide.

Comment: thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove every `AS`, they don't belong.  Function variables/parameters don't have `@` in front of them.  You need a `;` at the end of the RETURN statement.

Wherever you are learning function syntax is clearly not correct or you are not reading carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to use delimiter because the function definition contains no internal ; statement delimiters:

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION scalar_func (a int ,b int)
    -> RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    ->        RETURN a+b ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)


mysql> select scalar_func(10,12);;
+--------------------+
| scalar_func(10,12) |
+--------------------+
|                 22 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[Check for more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) and [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions.php#:%7E:text=In%20MySQL%2C%20a%20function%20is,and%20then%20return%20a%20value.)